# how to get access inner array of an object in dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json file with this structure:

```json
[
    {
        "_id": "62b2ebff955fe1001d225781",
        "datasetName": "comments",
        "action": "dataset",
        "comment": "Initial data!",
        "instances": [
            "62b2eb94955fe1001d22576a",
            "62b2eba1955fe1001d22576e",
            "62b2eba9955fe1001d225770",
            "62b2ebb9955fe1001d225772",
            "62b2ebcc955fe1001d225774",
            "62b2ebe2955fe1001d225778"
        ],
        "label": [
            "Contemporary",
            "Tango"
        ]
    }
]
```

I wanted to know how can I access the `values of "label"` and also how can I count the `length of "instances"` object.

Answer (score 0):

So your json is a list of dict. You can load it with the json standard library. Then you can iterate over the elements in the list. As each of these elements is a dict item, you can then get the `instances` list by it's key. As it is a list, you can simple call the `len()` function to get the length.

See the code below as an example:

```py
import json


with open("somefile.json") as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)
    for element in data:
        print(len(element["instances"]))
```

Note that if your json file contains more elements in the root list, it will of course print out the length of the `instances` list for each of these elements.